# How can we put the initial centroids in FCM function ( Matlab )

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, centroid

I am using fcm function in Matlab to clustering. However, the initial centroids are set randomly. I need to set the initial centroids values by myself. I am thinking to modify the stepfcm function in Matlab. Could anyone tell me how can I put the initial centroids by myself?

Comment: look at [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/examples/fuzzy-c-means-clustering-for-iris-data.html) example, they use `initfcm` and `stepfcm`. you can just generate your own data instead of `initfcm`'s.

Answer (score 2):

I did `edit('fcm.m')`.
On line 84 (I use MATLAB R2016b) you have:

`U = initfcm(cluster_n, data_n);            % Initial fuzzy partition`

This is the initialization of clusters centroids.
If you replace it with your own you'll get what you want.

#### How To?

On MATLAB's command line run the command `edit('fcm.m')`.
Save a copy of it with the name `FcmInit`.
Change the function signature from `[center, U, obj_fcn] = fcm(data, cluster_n, options)` To `[center, obj_fcn] = FcmInit(data, cluster_n, U, options)`.
Delete the line `U = initfcm(cluster_n, data_n);` so it won't overwrite the input.

Comment: thanks! But I have the centroid values , how to transfer them into U values?

Comment: You copy the function `fcm.m` into your own function and edit the line I pointed at. You can even set it as input parameter.

Comment: Can you please show that in your above answer ? I have a set of data and a set of centroid values. How can I set the U values for initial centroids?

Comment: you mean I put the U initialization of clusters centroids. But I dont have U , I just have the initial centroid values. I think we should calculate U from the initial centroid values first.

Comment: Centroids are vectors. U is composed of that vectors.

Comment: Do you mean that the initial_centroids=initial_U ?